# 2nd button row from WP Super Edit or TinyMCE Advanced doesn't show to 2nd admin

Tags: posts, editor, tinymce, post-editor, plugin-tinymce

I'm currently using WP Super Edit. But the same problem persists with TinyMCE Advanced.

This is how it is configured:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXqhx.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbdAL.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8W0G.png

This is how I (admin) see it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzQ1B.png

This is how my friend (2nd admin) sees it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHQRb.png

I'm getting desperate figuring out why the hell the 2nd button bar doesn't show.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try click the "**show/hide kitchen sink**" button that looks like this:
[image]

Comment: i fail to see the point it that button - especially with resizable editor box